# bootstrap выравнивание нескольких таблиц

Tags: css, bootstrap, angularjs, angular2

ищу помощи по правильному формированию списков характеристик товара, остановился на отображении в виде таблицы, однако имею неприятность с выравниванием.
стиль использую Bootstrap'a -> Отображаю Angular'ом

в результате получаю как на скриншоте [скриншот](https://ibb.co/rFR76xG)

Мб я вообще в корне, строю отображение не правильно?

таблицу строю так

```
<table class="table" *ngFor="let specification of details.specifications">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">{{specification.section}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let spec of specification.specifications">
      <td>{{spec.name}}</td>
      <td class="font-weight-bold text-success">
        {{spec.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

модель данных для примера

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Материнская плата Gigabyte GA-Z270P-D3 Soc-1151 Intel Z270 4xDDR4 ATX AC`97 8ch(7.1) GbLAN RAID+HDMI",
  "specifications": [
    {
      "section": "Поддержка дисков",
      "specifications": [
        {
          "name": "Поддержка RAID 10",
          "value": "Да",
          "sorting": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Поддержка RAID 5",
          "value": "Да",
          "sorting": 24
        },
        {
          "name": "Поддержка RAID 1",
          "value": "Да",
          "sorting": 23
        },
        {
          "name": "Поддержка RAID 0",
          "value": "Да",
          "sorting": 22
        },
        {
          "name": "Поддержка RAID",
          "value": "ДА",
          "sorting": 21
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "section": "Память",
      "specifications": [
        {
          "name": "Слотов памяти DDR4",
          "value": "4",
          "sorting": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Частотная спецификация памяти",
          "value": "2400",
          "sorting": 14
        },
        {
          "name": "Поддержка частот оперативной памяти",
          "value": "3866(O.C.) / 3800(O.C.) / 3733(O.C.) / 3666(O.C.) / 3600(O.C.) / 3466(O.C.) / 3400(O.C.) / 3333(O.C.) / 3300(O.C.) / 3200(O.C.) / 3000(O.C.) / 2800(O.C.) / 2666(O.C.) / 2400 / 2133 МГц",
          "sorting": 13
        },
        {
          "name": "Максимальный объем оперативной памяти",
          "value": "64",
          "sorting": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Режим работы оперативной памяти",
          "value": "двухканальный",
          "sorting": 16
        },
        {
          "name": "Поддержка Intel Optane",
          "value": "ДА",
          "sorting": 1048
        },
        {
          "name": "Тип поддерживаемой памяти",
          "value": "DIMM",
          "sorting": 12
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "section": "Процессор",
      "specifications": [
        {
          "name": "Northbridge",
          "value": "Intel Z270",
          "sorting": 6
        }
      ]
    },
    { ... и далее }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Вроде бы все верно. Вам следует со стилями играться. Попробуйте написать стили таблицы без использования бутстрапа, возможно из-за этого у вас не получается, внутри бутстрапа написаны стили которые мешают добиться желаемого результата

Comment: P.S: У меня много раз так было, и приходилось избавляться, и теперь из всего бутстрапа, я в проектах использую только их сетку..

Comment: я в стилях не силен, можно стиль который выравнивает 2ую колонку или направление где копать

Comment: Так в чем проблема конкретно?

Comment: посмотрите скрин, значения хар-к криво выходят, зеленые должны быть в 1 колонке

Comment: Скрин конечно же смотрел. То что для вас криво - для других вполне ожидаемо и ок. Так происходит потому что у вас разные таблицы. Поставьте всем таблицам одинаковые размеры td через css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте *col-* * для *td*. Например так:

```
<tr *ngFor="let spec of specification.specifications">
  <td class="col-4">{{spec.name}}</td>
  <td class="font-weight-bold text-success col-8">
    {{spec.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Должно помочь

Comment: Я решил вопрос, в любом случае спасибо